# Sample every nth element of numpy array, repeat by moving start index m times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Title might be confusing, so it's easier if I explain what my goal is with some code:

```py
arr = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4])
n_sub = 3
outs = [arr[i::n_sub] for i in range(n_sub)]
# outs returns [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 
                array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 
                array([1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

Is there a built-in numpy function that does this?

EDIT:

What if the array is not simply 1D, e.g.

```py
arr = np.array([[1,1], [1,1], [1,1], 
                [2,2], [2,2], [2,2], 
                [3,3], [3,3], [3,3],
                [4,4], [4,4], [4,4]
])
# outs computed as above returns
#[array([[1, 1],
#        [2, 2],
#        [3, 3],
#        [4, 4]]),
# array([[1, 1],
#        [2, 2],
#        [3, 3],
#        [4, 4]]),
# array([[1, 1],
#        [2, 2],
#        [3, 3],
#        [4, 4]])]
```

(the simple for loop method given above still gives the correct result)

Comment: ```arr.reshape(-1, n_sub).T```

Comment: Just edited the post to ask also about multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: you could use [`arr.flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

Comment: what would be the expected output if you use the 2D example?

Comment: added that information @mozway

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) in Fortran order:

```
n_sub = 3
arr = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
arr.reshape(n_sub, -1, order='F')
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

As a list:

```
n_sub = 3
list(arr1.reshape(n_sub, -1, order='F'))
# [array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

2D variant:

```
arr = np.array([[1,1],[1,1], [1,1,], [2,2], [2,2], [2,2], [3,3], [3,3], [3,3]])

n_sub = 3
arr.reshape((n_sub, -1, 2), order='F')
# or: list(arr.reshape((n_sub, -1, 2), order='F')) for a list of arrays
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]]])
```

Programatically (works for both 1D and 2D):

```
n_sub = 3
out = arr.reshape((n_sub, -1)+arr.shape[1:], order='F')
# or: out = list(arr.reshape((n_sub, -1)+arr.shape[1:], order='F'))
```

Comment: Well, this only works when ```len(arr) == n_sub**2```  . If ```len(arr) != n_sub**2```, then ```[arr[i::len_sub] for i in range(n_sub)]``` and ```arr.reshape((3, -1)+arr.shape[1:], order='F')``` doesn't give same results

Comment: @Murali I assumed this was indeed the case on the last dimension, this is what OP's example show at least. If not, numpy cannot really do this without looping.

Comment: I've edited my post to get rid of the `len(arr) == n_sub**2` special case.

Comment: I believe my answer still works with the updated examples. Actually the dimension must not be a square but a simple multiple.

Comment: @mozway I was generalising for more dimensions. when I checked it for 4D they both did not match (for ex: arr = np.random.rand(20,4,3,2)). you are right, in this case I guess we need to loop